MSAL react in docker pod (on prem cluster) login for pcs that can only connect to on prem network and not the outside
Currently I am using msal react for authentication, the react app is running on a pod within on an prem kubernetes cluster. However today I learned that some pcs within the factory have no access to outside internet, meaning only on prem traffic is allowed (to the cluster or one of the servers). Seeing how you get redirected to a page www.onmicrosoft.... for login I don't think it is possible, currently there is also no way to test it. Will this approach work or do we have to use another authentication strategy?

The React application is running in the end user's browser; even if the code is served from Kubernetes, the application itself runs outside the cluster in the browser.  If the end user's system can't connect to the public Internet, then you can't readily use a cloud-based authentication strategy.
